# How to place my <p>texts</p> after the end of the background image, keeping leading <h1> as is?

Tags: html, css, background-image

The url is https://sputnick.fr/

The HTML is:

```css
body {
  background-color: #15141A;
  background-image: url("https://sputnick.fr/header.jpg");
  color: white;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<h1>foobar</h1>
<p>lorem ipsum doloris</p>
<p>lorem ipsum doloris</p>
<p>lorem ipsum doloris</p>
<p>lorem ipsum doloris</p>
```

I searched MDN and other ressources, but I don't get how to do this.

I want all `<p>xxxx</p>` after the background image.

Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "after"?  Like, after it in the DOM flow?  Z-index?  I went to your link but I don't immediately see anything wrong or broken.  Do you want all of your text to be physically below/underneath your first header image?

Comment: Post edited accordingly, and yes @Jake: `Do you want all of your text to be physically below/underneath your first header image? `

Comment: You can do it by adding padding or margin at the bottom of the h1 tag. Check this code pen: https://codepen.io/gd17/pen/LYJyoeM

    .heading
{
   margin-bottom: 18%;
}
I have added a custom class "heading" to h1 and added % based CSS padding.

Comment: @dostogircse171 Very nice, add it in answer, I will accept it

Comment: By adding background-repeat: no-repeat; I have updated the codepen you may check. But the problem is the image you used is smaller in size. The image can be extended using CSS with background-size:cover but this will stretch the image wider. Try image size 1920x1080

Comment: I will accept the one that works on smartphone ;) And yes, I use now 'no repeat'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by adding padding or margin at the bottom of the h1 tag.

Check this code pen: [codepen.io/gd17/pen/LYJyoeM](https://codepen.io/gd17/pen/LYJyoeM)

`.heading { margin-bottom: 18%; }`

I have added a custom class "heading" to h1 and added % based CSS padding.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear whether or not you want the repeating background images, but the foolproof way to say "I want X after Y" is to make them different, consecutive elements in the DOM order.  Something like

```css
header{
  background-image: url("https://sputnick.fr/header.jpg");
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

h1{
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>
    Site Title
  </h1>
</header>
<main>
  <p>
    Some content
  </p>
  <p>
    Some more content
  </p>
</main>
```

If you DO want the background-image to repeat throughout your entire webpage, you have lots of options, but I would probably do something like this

```css
.wrapper{
  background-image: url("https://sputnick.fr/header.jpg");
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}

.content{
  margin-top: 650px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>
    Site Title
  </h1>
  <div class="content">
    <p>
    Some text
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This does rely on a hard-coded margin-top that matches the height of your background-image - if this height ever changes, then this code will break.  If that is a likely scenario, then you could also consider doing kind of a tandem of both approaches

```css
body{
  background-image: url("https://sputnick.fr/header.jpg");
  color: white;
}
h1{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
  
    <img src="https://sputnick.fr/header.jpg">
    <h1>
      Site Title
    </h1>
</header>
  <main>
      <p>
      Some content
    </p>
    <p>
      Some more content
    </p>
  </main>
</body>
```

This has the disadvantage of relying on `position: absolute`, but will behave better if you ever change your background image's dimensions.

Hopefully this gives you some ideas to work with!

Answer (score 1):

You have set a background image on the `<body>` element which means the whole page. If you want to have content appear after an image, apply the background image to an element like `<main>` instead.

```css
main {
  background-color: #15141A;
  background-image: url("https://sputnick.fr/header.jpg");
  color: white;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 16px;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main>
<h1>foobar</h1>
</main>
<aside>
<p>lorem ipsum doloris</p>
<p>lorem ipsum doloris</p>
<p>lorem ipsum doloris</p>
<p>lorem ipsum doloris</p>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want that background-image only behind the `h1` header? Well, then assign it only to the `h1`. Add `padding` to make it higher and set `margin-top` to `0` to make it start right at the top.

```css
body {
  background-color: #15141A;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 16px;
}
h1 {
  background-image: url("https://sputnick.fr/header.jpg");
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>foobar</h1>
<p>lorem ipsum doloris</p>
<p>lorem ipsum doloris</p>
<p>lorem ipsum doloris</p>
<p>lorem ipsum doloris</p>
```